# Can we use OpenGL in Visual Studio 2010 in Visual basic project?

Tags: vb.net, opengl

I want to use "OpenGL" in my project. Is it possible to associate it with "Visual Basic" application developed in Visual Studio 2010? If yes then how can we do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible, either import OpenGL functions as extern "C" functions from OpenGL32.dll (just as you would do with any other WinAPI functions), or use the whole library as seen in the tutorial below.

What about using google? Try http://home.pacific.net.hk/~edx/othersamples.htm

Comment: I am a beginner. So i don't understand what you have quoted. Can u please explain easily if possible with example or procedure?

Comment: Ok, so then no no importing functions. Click http://csgl.sourceforge.net/faq.html#vsnet, read it, download it, use it. How about that?

Comment: If you are a beginner why are you trying do something so advanced?